# How to avoid overhead while still implementing null object pattern?

Tags: java

I am implementing a binary search tree in java. Inside the BST class I have a protected class Node (in case I want to extend to an AVL tree). The code is below. I had a problem, both conceptually and aesthetically, implementing empty nodes as null pointers. So instead I opted for the null object pattern and created an EmptyNode object, the code for which is also below. However, even though this gives me prettier code and something more conceptually pleasing (to me), I now have the problem that when I'm working with a tree of height n, I can have as many as 2^{n+1} - 2^{n} instances of this EmptyNode class floating around, which takes up space for no good reason.

How should I fix this code to avoid this overhead while still implementing the null object pattern? I feel like the EmptyNode should be something conceptually similar to a constant field of Node, but I can't implement that. I also feel like there should be only one copy of EmptyNode being referenced anywhere, but I can't figure out how to implement that either. Any help or recommendations are appreciated.

```
protected class Node<Key,E>{
    protected Key key;
    protected E value;
    protected Node<Key,E> left;
    protected Node<Key,E> right;
    protected int height;
    protected int balanceFactor;
    public Node(){}
    public Node(Key k, E v){
        key = k;
        value = v;
        left = new EmptyNode<Key,E>();
        right = new EmptyNode<Key,E>();
        height = 0;
        balanceFactor = 0;
    }
    public Node(Key k, E v, Node<Key,E> l, Node<Key,E> r){
        key = k;
        value = v;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        height = Math.max(l.height(), r.height())+1;
        balanceFactor = l.height() - r.height();
    }
    public Key getKey(){return key;}
    public E getValue(){return value;}
    public Node<Key,E> getLeft(){return left;}
    public Node<Key,E> getRight(){return right;}
    public int height(){return height;}
    public int balanceFactor(){return balanceFactor;}
    public void setKey(Key k){key = k;}
    public void setValue(E v){value = v;}
    public void setLeft(Node<Key,E> l){
        left = l;
        height = Math.max(l.height(), this.right.height())+1;
        balanceFactor = left.height() - this.right.height();
    }
    public void setRight(Node<Key,E> r){
        right = r;
        height = Math.max(this.left.height(), r.height())+1;
        balanceFactor = this.left.height() - right.height();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){return false;}
    public boolean isLeaf(){
        return (left.isEmpty()) && (right.isEmpty());
    }
    public boolean hasLeft(){
        return !left.isEmpty();
    }
    public boolean hasRight(){
        return !right.isEmpty();
    }
}
protected final class EmptyNode<Key,E> extends Node<Key,E>{
    public EmptyNode(){
        key = null;
        value = null;
        left = right = null;
        height = -1;
        balanceFactor = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void setKey(Key k){}
    @Override
    public void setValue(E v){}
    @Override
    public void setLeft(Node<Key,E> l){}
    @Override
    public void setRight(Node<Key,E> r){}
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(){return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(){return false;}
    @Override
    public boolean hasLeft(){return false;}
    @Override
    public boolean hasRight(){return false;}
}
```

Comment: Why does your empty node even provide `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods? It does not make sense to ask for key or value of an empty node, so the type system should disallow that. (Also, you can call `setKey(x)` on an empty node but later `getKey()` returns `null`. This behavior is very confusing, I wouldn't expect an instance of `Node` to behave like that).

Comment: @hmp I agree, I haven't used those methods elsewhere on an EmptyNode and I will alter the code to reflect that. However, this code is working and that always counts for something when you can't  appease your OCD.

Comment: What stops you from having a single instance of an empty node in a static variable? Any time you need an empty node, grab that one.

Comment: If an `EmptyNode` cannot safely be used in the same context as any other node (for example, you end up with lots of `if (node instanceof EmptyNode)`, that suggests it is not really a `Node`.  So why force it to be a `Node` when it is not?  It's a matter of opinion, sure, but I learned early in my SE career the downsides to forcing things that are not the same to be the same (essentially using polymorphism for types that are not compatible).

Comment: Again, my own opinion, but `OperationNotSupportedException` is a sign of what I described: forcing a class to appear compatible with something that it is not truly compatible with.  This is used several times in the solution below.

Comment: There's a tradeoff between deciding whether or not the EmptyNode should extend a Node. Deciding that it does extend a normal node, entails the UnsupportedOperationException and having methods that will never be invoked; however, we do get conceptual consistency. In addition, this approach also lets me implement an AVL tree which extends from this BST class I'm creating. The EmptyNode plays a more important role in an AVL tree, and not having it extend from a normal Node creates awkward code over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single instance of `EmptyNode<Object, Object>`, and cast it to `Node<Key, E>` when you need an empty node for a specific key and value type. This will work because an empty node has `null` key and value, and `null` reference can be casted to any reference type. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.emptyList%28%29) for `Collections.emptyList()` for an example of this approach.

A fully working code example:

```
public class NodeTest {
    protected static class Node<Key,E>{
        private static final Node<?, ?> EMPTY_NODE = new EmptyNode<>();

        protected Key key;
        protected E value;
        protected Node<Key,E> left;
        protected Node<Key,E> right;
        protected int height;
        protected int balanceFactor;
        public Node() {
            this(null, null);
        }
        public Node(Key k, E v){
            this(k, v, Node.<Key, E>emptyNode(), Node.<Key, E>emptyNode());
        }
        public Node(Key k, E v, Node<Key,E> l, Node<Key,E> r){
            this(k, v, l, r, Math.max(l.height(), r.height())+1, l.height() - r.height());
        }
        private Node(Key k, E v, Node<Key, E> l, Node<Key, E> r, int h, int bf) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
            left = l;
            right = r;
            height = h;
            balanceFactor = bf;
        }
        public Key getKey(){return key;}
        public E getValue(){return value;}
        public Node<Key,E> getLeft(){return left;}
        public Node<Key,E> getRight(){return right;}
        public int height(){return height;}
        public int balanceFactor(){return balanceFactor;}
        public void setKey(Key k){key = k;}
        public void setValue(E v){value = v;}
        public void setLeft(Node<Key,E> l){
            left = l;
            height = Math.max(l.height(), this.right.height())+1;
            balanceFactor = left.height() - this.right.height();
        }
        public void setRight(Node<Key,E> r){
            right = r;
            height = Math.max(this.left.height(), r.height())+1;
            balanceFactor = this.left.height() - right.height();
        }
        public boolean isEmpty(){return false;}
        public boolean isLeaf(){
            return (left.isEmpty()) && (right.isEmpty());
        }
        public boolean hasLeft(){
            return !left.isEmpty();
        }
        public boolean hasRight(){
            return !right.isEmpty();
        }

        /**
         * @return empty node. This method can be useful for subclasses
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected static final <Key, E> Node<Key, E> emptyNode() {
            return (Node<Key, E>) EMPTY_NODE;
        }
    }

    private static final class EmptyNode<Key, E> extends Node<Key, E> {
        private EmptyNode() {
            super(null, null, null, null, -1, 0);
        }
        @Override
        public void setKey(Key k){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
        @Override
        public void setValue(E v){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
        @Override
        public void setLeft(Node<Key,E> l){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
        @Override
        public void setRight(Node<Key,E> r){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty(){return true;}
        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(){return false;}
        @Override
        public boolean hasLeft(){return false;}
        @Override
        public boolean hasRight(){return false;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String, Integer> node = new Node<>("hello", 5);
        System.out.println(node.isEmpty()); // prints false
        System.out.println(node.isLeaf());  // prints true
        System.out.println(node.getLeft().isEmpty()); // prints true
        System.out.println(node.getRight().isEmpty()); // prints true
    }
}
```

My previous solution was bad. The new solution is better: shorter, and re-using more of your code. My modifications of your code were the following.

- Routed all constructor calls to the private constructor which initializes all the fields (`key`, `value`, `left`, `right`, `balanceFactor`). This way, if you want to expand the fields a `Node` holds, you have to alter the assignment statements in only one constructor, reducing the potential for error.
- Implemented public no-arguments constructor for a `Node` (yours did not initialize the left and right subtrees to be empty, they were `null`). Now it actually creates a changeable node with initial `null` key and value.
- Extended `Node` to get `EmptyNode`. The `EmptyNode` constructor just calls `super` to create a node with `null` key, value, left and right subtrees, `height` of `-1` and `balanceFactor` of `0`.
- Added `emptyNode()` method, which returns an appropriately casted `EmptyNode` instance (see the description of this technique at the beginning of my answer). This method can be used by subclasses of `Node` to obtain the shared `EmptyNode` instance instead of creating their own.
- Made `setKey()`, `setValue()`, `setLeft()` and `setRight()` of `EmptyNode` throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, signaling that the empty node is immutable.
- Made `Node` and `EmptyNode` static classes. I believe most inner classes should be `static` unless you *absolutely* have to use their containing class's fields and methods.

Comment: I've been attempting to apply this approach to my code, but it's an understatement to say that it has been frustrating. I have a couple questions. First, shouldn't EmptyNode<Key, E> extend Node<Key, E> so that it has the same fields? Second, do you mean 'implements INode<Key,E>' in your 4th to last line? Third, should there be some parens after 'EmptyNode<>'? And why don't you specify the generics with it?

Comment: If you use Java 7 and later, you can omit the specification of generics if it is apparent from the context, e.g. `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()` and `public List<String> getList() { return new ArrayList<>(); }`. Google for "diamond operator Java 7" to see more examples of this.

Comment: It also might be more logical for empty node to: 1) return empty left and right subnodes, instead of null (see my comment in the updated code); 2) disallow setting the key and value (say, by throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`, which is customary for Java Collections framework).

Comment: I got something to compile with the intended functionality. I had to change some INodes to Nodes though. I'm working out the final details. (These classes and the interface you helped with are actually wrapped in a larger class in the final code and I had to add a static keyword to the class Node; that caused some problems unrelated to what we discussed here). I'll post a link to the final code within a day.

Comment: No problem. I added the `static` keyword to `Node` and got rid of the `INode` (the interface here is not strictly needed.) See my updated (again) answer :-)

Comment: I read up on type inference because I didn't understand what would happen if I called 'root = Node.emptyNode()' where 'root' was earlier declared to be a Node<Key, E> object. And from what I understand, it's the same as 'root = Node.<Key, E>emptyNode()'. Is that right?

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately, type inference in Java 5,6,7 is too limited. It basically cannot infer types outside of declarations and assignments. E.g., if you have a `<T> void m(List<T> list)` method, you cannot call it with `Collections.emptyList()`, you have to supply `Collections.<T>emptyList()` or write `List<T> someList = Collections.emptyList(); m(someList);`. The same for ternary operator: `<T> List<T> opt(List<T> list) { return list == null ? Collections.emptyList() : list }` won't work; but `if (list == null) { return Collections.emptyList(); } else { return list; }` will.

Comment: Java 8 apparently adds more powerful type inference: see [JEP 101](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) for details.

Comment: Here's the final code: https://gist.github.com/blmalikov/34bb5b1566f61a591706. Many thanks for your help!